Galois groups of p-adic fields isomorphic to surface groups
The presentation of the absolute Galois groups of p-adic fields proved by Jannsen-Wingberg and others is described in a few sources as being "analogous" to that of surface groups. (I understand why this is the case.) But I am having trouble seeing the following:
Question: Are there p-adic fields whose absolute galois group is actually isomorphic to the profinite completion of a surface group?
I see the relation that would need to be killed, but not how to do it.

Infinite Galois groups are uncountable, surface groups are countable.

Oops, good call. Edited to reflect completions.

Thanks! It seems as though things get closer but still no cigar after taking maximal p-quotient. If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.
